# Running a complex command line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, command-line, popen

I would like to call a complex command line in Python and capture its output, and I don't understand how I should be doing it:

Command line that I'm trying to run is:

```
cat codegen_query_output.json | jq -r '.[0].code' | echoprint-inverted-query index.bin
```

As far as I got is:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-a'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
print out
```

but this is a simple ls -a ([cmd, args]) any idea how should I run/structure my complex command line call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way is to create 2 subprocesses piped together. You don't need a subprocess for the `cat` command, just pass an opened file handle:

```
import subprocess

with open("codegen_query_output.json") as input_stream:
    jqp = subprocess.Popen(["jq","-r",'.[0].code'],stdin=input_stream,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ep = subprocess.Popen(["echoprint-inverted-query","index.bin"],stdin=jqp.stdout,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = ep.stdout.read()
    return_code = ep.wait() or jqp.wait()
```

The `jqp` process takes the file contents as input. Its output is passed to `ep` input.

In the end we read output from `ep` to get the final result. The `return_code` is a combination of both return codes. If something goes wrong, it's different from 0 (more detailed return code info would be to test separately of course)

Standard error isn't considered here. It will be displayed to the console, unless `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` is set (to merge with piped output)

This method doesn't require a shell or `shell=True`, it's then more portable and secure.

Comment: It worked like a sharm! I like the idea to not need to use shell for it.

Answer (score 3):

It takes a shell to interpret [operators like `|`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pipelines).  You can ask Python to run a shell, and pass your command as the thing to execute:

```
cmd = "cat test.py | tail -n3"                                                  
process = subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-c', cmd], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)         
out, err = process.communicate()                                                
print out
```

Comment: I cannot mark both answers as good, this version was working too, although I like previous answer because I like the idea to avoid using bash command. Thanks anyway!!